# Menu keeps hiding behind other elements on page

Tags: css

I know this seems silly, but this menu is driving me nutty. I've fixed it a few times, but it keeps coming back and biting me in the butt.

The menu looks like this. And as you can see half of it is cut off so you cannot read the words.[image]

I have tried many ways to fix this. I have moved the menu around in the html, tried positioning it and adding a z-index. But I have had no luck.

The html looks like this

```
<div class="pull-right" style="padding-top: 0px;">
            <!-- drop button -->
            <div class="btn-group js_editTab-wrapper open" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id' : id, 'data-type' : entityType}" data-id="25402" data-type="KioskPageControl">


              <!-- ko if : $data.editTabs -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropBorder" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: $data.editTabs">
                <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data" class="js_editTab noLink">Appearance</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data" class="js_editTab noLink">Identification</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data" class="js_editTab noLink">Parameters</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data" class="js_editTab noLink">Rules</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <span class="drag btn-xs btn-labeled btn-info">
                <span class="btn-label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></span>
            </span>
            &nbsp;
            <span class="remove btn-xs btn-labeled btn-danger">
                <span class="btn-label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

and the css for the menu looks like this

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
list-style: none;
overflow: visible;
```

Obviously the display none turns to block when clicked on the dropdown menu and the blue bar does have a z-index on it of 1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I know it is probably a lot of code. But could you post the whole css ? There is a good chance this is caused by some other element if z-index doesnt fix it. It would be awesome if you could replicate this in a fiddle or something

Comment: I think your main container (this one who is ended on blue bg) have overflow hidden. I have the same problem few days ago.

Comment: @sinanspd, It's an enterprise application so there is no way I can post the whole thing. I've inspected the crap out of this thing and the css above is the only thing attached to it.

And I can never get fiddles to work.

Comment: @SkyWookie, that blue thing is a button and I've checked it does not have an overflow on it. That was the first thing I looked at haha

Comment: EDIT: this comment is moot, someone asked it right before I finished. :( Original comment was as follows: If I were to guess, this is probably related to the parent of your dropdown having enforced boundaries (via `overflow:hidden;`), as you cannot escape your parent with z-index, only your siblings. And those of your generation who are descendants of the same z-i chain as you (I think).

Comment: Is the button in your sample html or no? And if it is, where?

Comment: @abluejelly, There is actually no overflow attached to the parents except for the visible one's that I have added. I've gone all the way to the top and no where are there hiddens. That's why this has me stumped.

Comment: postion: absolute/relative can disrupt the stacking order of page elements. You may need to look at css on parents for both elements to troubleshoot. Good (but longish) article on it here: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @abluejelly It is not, the page is extremely complicated so I could not post that here. The only thing on that button though is a position relative.

Comment: @Joseph reading that now.... What sorcery is this. Thanks haha

Comment: Can You paste bigger screenshot? It could give us better understanding.

Comment: Well then :/ One other thing I can suggest is inspecting those 2 elements using chrome debugger or something. If you are using a library/framework something might be getting overwriten

Comment: Reading through the thing Joseph linked, I was in the right forest, just up the wrong tree. As for how to fix it.... you're going to have to get that button into the same stacking context as your dropdown, otherwise it'll be literally physically impossible. Once you manage that part, though, you're golden, as the z-indexen will behave as expected. An easier (probably) "hack" solution would be to hide that button when the dropdown's displayed, then unhide it once the ddl's hidden again.